# Can't get error messages for model submit to one controller show with another Rails 2.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, render, form-for

I have read up on other people's posts about this and I still can't get my head wrapped around the problem I am having. So I thought I would ask.

I have a form that gets for uploading an avatar.
This form is displayed from :controller => 'board', :action => 'show'

```
<% form_tag("avatar/upload", :multipart => true ) do %>
  <%= error_messages_for :avatar %>
  ...
```

This works great. Problem is that I can't get the error messages to display.

The upload is handled by :controller => 'avatar', :action => 'upload'

```
if params_posted?(:avatar)
  image = get_image(params)
  @board = Board.find(session[:board_id])
  @avatar = Avatar.new(@board.id, image)
  if @avatar.save
    # ???
  end
end
```

Now this is the part that I have trouble with. I know I can't do a redirect_to or I will lose the  error_messages_for @avatar and thus get no error messages but doing a render is a problem because I have some routes.

In my routes.rb I have the following:

```
map.connect 'board/celebrating/:id/:name', :controller => 'board', :action => 'show'
```

So what I want to know is how to display the board again located at :controller => 'board', :action => 'show' and display the error messages for @avatar?

Sorry if this seems trivial. To me its been a struggle.
Thank you in advance.

Mitchell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by rendering a template instead of redirecting or rendering an action. For example, if you want to render the boards/show.html.erb on a failure, you would do the following:

```
if params_posted?(:avatar)
  image = get_image(params)
  @board = Board.find(session[:board_id])
  @avatar = Avatar.new(@board.id, image)
  if @avatar.save
    ...
  else
    render :template => 'boards/show'
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that the BoardsController#show action will not be run, so your flash messages and instance variables (@avatar, @board) will be preserved.